Fourier Transform of product of unit vectors
I have a general integral of the form
$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi e^{-i F \cos(\phi)} \left(\cos(\phi) \hat{x}+ \sin(\phi) \hat{y}\right)^m$$
That is, in the end, I get bunch of tensors with chains of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ with different powers of $\cos(\phi)^a \sin(\phi)^b$.
This seems to give bunch of different Bessel functions of first kind $J_\alpha$ with different $\alpha$. I was wondering if there's a interesting way to group these terms to give Bessel functions of definite $\alpha$, with some high value of $m$. This seems possible for small $m$, but I'm having trouble to organize it for arbitrary $m$ and the available integral representation doesn't seem to map intuitively to the form I have.

Is the exponent $m$ supposed to represent a tensorial power ?

Yes exactly. As the first equation shows
